# How can i populate a RecyclerView with hashmap values?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, hashmap

Before i used an ArrayList for this, but because of duplicate Album issues (which i resolved before API29 by using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` statements) which are not allowed anymore to use inside a query.

I got values like this in my RecyclerViews Adapter: `myArrayList.get(position).getAlbum();`

But now that i'm using a **HashMap**, how can i get a value by position which i get from the adapter?

**Code for adding values in Hashmap**

```
HashMap<Integer, Album> albums = new HashMap<>();

String[] projection2 = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC};

String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";

String sort = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, projection2, selection, null, sort);

try {
      if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                 int columnAlbumId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
                 int columnAlbumName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);

                 String albumId = cursor.getString(columnAlbumId);
                 String albumName = cursor.getString(columnAlbumName);

                 if(albums.containsKey(albumId) == false){
                   Album album = new Album(albumId, albumName);
                   albums.put(albumId, album);
                 }
                cursor.moveToNext();
          }
       }
    }catch (Exception e){
     Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught when creating ALBUM!", e);
     throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the `HashMap` is not sorted so how about a `SortedMap`? An implementation of a `SortedMap` is a `TreeMap` which sorts the entries **according to keys** (or a `Comparator`).

I believe that suits you since your map has integers as keys.

Edit:
You can use a `List` or whatever collection suits you in your adapter. For example keep a reference to the ids and the albums which is the data that you're interested in displaying through the adapter.

```
private int[] ids;
private Album[] albums;
```

As you're passing the data (included in a map) to your adapter then you could extract that data and place it in the array containers so you can take advantage of the index. For example,

```
public MyAdapter(Map<Integer,Album> data){
        ids = new int[map.size()];
        albums = new Album[map.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Album> e : map.entrySet()){
            ids[i] = e.getKey();
            albums[i++] = e.getValue();
        }
    }
```

Now that you have your arrays you can sort them also if you like and in case you want to grab the 3rd album and its id all you need to do is,

```
int id = ids[2];
Album album = albums[2];
```

Comment: But how can i implement a SortedMap inside a RecyclerView? I need to get values by adapter position, so for ex. the first 10 items have the positions 0-9 and with an Arraylist i did get values like this myArraylist.get(position).getAlbum();. Not sure how i can achieve the same thing with a SortedMap.

Comment: Reason i stopped using the ArrayList is because i can't get rid of the duplicate albums which i got rid of before using SQL statements like DISTINCT and GROUP BY but Api 29 and above stopped supporting this and doesn't work anymore. So what i'm trying to achieve is getting a link between the Hashmap keys and the adapter position in a RecyclerView.